# Servlet Programming Using Eclipse IDE

Tags: servlets

I have started learning servlet programming. I am using eclipse IDE. I have created a simple dynamic web project and have one html file and one servlet program in it(LoginForm.html & LoginServlet.java). I want to display the html page to the user at first .I have also set up the welcome-file-list tag in the web.xml but when I run the project it doesn't display that page. I also tried to enter the url in the browser manually but it's also not working.It is giving the error as '404-Page not found'. My web.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>LoginApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>LoginForm.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myprograms.servlet.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/logapp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The URL I am using is `http://localhost:8001/LoginApp/LoginForm.html.` Please suggest any solution.

Comment: Are you sure about the port where the servlet is listening?

Comment: @AleSequeira: He could not get a 404 if there was no server.

Comment: Without knowing the structure of your webapp, if it's deployed, and the URL you tried, I don't see how we could help.

Comment: The server port is correct. I have configured it to be 8001. The URL I am using is http://localhost:8001/LoginApp/LoginForm.html

Comment: does your LoginForm.html is inside LoginApp folder and is in turn inside war folder?

Comment: Yes my LoginForm.html file is in \LoginApp\src\com\myprograms\servlet folder.

Comment: Check if your server is running then look into folder where your app is deployed.

Comment: I recalled that you need to configure tomcat server correctly in eclipse which is tricky. Don't you use tomcat 7?

Comment: Yes I am using Tomcat 7, but does it matters anything? Please would you post the complete procedure to solve the problem?